# 2sxc Error: System.Exception: Module upgrade did not complete

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dotnetnuke-9

We just upgraded our DNN site to 9.1.1 and are now upgrading all of our modules. We saw 2sic's blog post about needing version 7+ of 2sxc installed before upgrading to 9 here: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/upgrading-to-2sxc-9-3-requires-2sxc-7, so we are trying to install version 8.12... but the installation won't finish. We have hit the "Complete Upgrade" upwards of 10 times now. We did see their other blog post about that here: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/understanding-upgrade-message-module-upgrade-did-not-complete, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: I'm seeing this error in the log whenever the button is pushed:
AbsoluteURL:/API/2sxc/view/module/finishinstallation
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:2bab59c2-2a60-4e76-955a-9e4de33f801c
ExceptionHash:vFqGbCEyticuCd1M5/wfUE++V7Y=
Message:Sequence contains more than one element
StackTrace:
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.DbAttributeSet.GetAttributeSet(String staticName) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\BLL\Parts\DbAttributeSet.cs:line 35 at  ...

Too long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Just to all who read this - the core cause was a duplicate item in this specific DB which we fixed manually.